# initialize an instance without any field in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to apply ioc into a school project. I have an abstract class `Application` without any field

```
public abstract class Application {
    abstract public void execute(ArrayList<String> args, OutputStream outputStream, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException;
}
```

And I will call the concrete class that extends `Application` by

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
Application app = (Application)context.getBean(appName);
```

My questions are:

1. Is it a bad practice to initialise a bean without any field (or all the fields are constants) using Spring?
2. As there is no dependency to other classes in `Application`, are we still consider this as a dependency injection or IOC? If no, what is the difference between this and a normal factory pattern? It seems that what Spring does here is simply matching the class and initializing it.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code snippet of the class where the instance of `Application` is needed.

```
String appName = argument.get(0);
Application app =  ApplicationFactory.getApplication(appName);
ArrayList<String> appArgs 
            = new ArrayList<String>(argument.subList(1, argument.size()));
app.execute(appArgs, outputStream, inputStream);
```

Further questions:

3. in my code the class `X` will call the instance of `Application` by specifying a concrete application class name. In this case, it is still not possible for Spring to inject the dependency to `Application`, right? As what I need is a concrete class but not `Application` itself.
4. if `Application` does have fields but these fields are initialsed somewhere higher than `X` (`X` receives them as inputs and passes them to `Application`), can I use DI in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to initialise a bean without any field (or all the fields are constants) using Spring?

No, its totally fine. Its true that you won't be able to "take advantage" of the automatic dependency injection mechanisms provided by spring (because obviously there are no dependencies in the class `Application` in your example), however spring can still:

1. Make sure that the Application as a singleton "obeys" the rule of being a single instance in the whole application context. For "manually" maintaining singletons you need to write code. Spring does it for you.
2. Manages the lifecycle of the object. Example, Spring has "postConstruct"/"preDestroy" methods that can can be run in the appropriate time and make example any custom code of the class Application.
3. If this class does some heavy-lifting (even without spring) than it can make sense to define it "lazy" so that the initialization of this instance will actually be done upon the first request to it.
4. Sometimes you/or spring itself will create a proxy of this class in runtime (for many different reasons, for example this aforementioned lazy functionality, but there are also other use cases). This is something that spring can do for you only if it manages the `Application` and not if its defined outside the spring.
5. Ok, you don't have dependencies in the application, This means that this `Application` class has some useful methods (at least on method, like `public void foo()` for
   simplicity). But this in turn means that there is some class (lets call it `X`) that calls this method. So this class has an instance of `Application` as a dependency. So now the real question is who manages this class `X`. Probably it makes sense to manage it in Spring as well, and then you will benefit of the Dependency Injection mechanisms in this class `X` only because `Application` is also managed by Spring. In general Spring can inject dependencies only if these dependencies are managed by Spring.
   I know, this last paragraph may sound vague given the use case you've presented, but you've got a point, for example in real application people make an initial bootstrapping in very certain places. Usually also people use spring boot that kind of encapsulates this kind of things for you.

> As there is no dependency to other classes in Application, are we still consider this as a dependency injection or IOC? If no, what is the difference between this and a normal factory pattern? It seems that what Spring does here is simply matching the class and initializing it.

So as you see, the concept of DI container goes far beyond of what the factory pattern has to offer. In short, factory pattern only specifies the way to **create** the objects. Spring on the other hand, not only creates the objects but also **manages** them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I have two questions arise from the fifth point. I update the post with them, can you please have a look on that? Thank you so much again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First, I very strongly suggest that you use Spring Boot instead of manually manipulating Spring at a low level like this.

It's perfectly ordinary to use beans that don't have their own fields for settings, but this is usually so that *other* beans can have pluggable strategies or providers and you can define in your application setup which to use.

If your `Application` class doesn't need anything else, then there really is not much advantage to Spring. Most real-world programs get complicated soon, however, and that's where it becomes useful.

Finally, you should almost never pass `ArrayList` as a parameter; use `List` instead. In the code you showed, however, if you have `String[] args`, you couldn't say `app.execute(Arrays.asList(args), System.out)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the suggestions, especially the one about using more general classes as parameters! I will take a look on the Spring Boot later.